# What is the difference between /dev/sda and /dev/hda?

Tags: hard-disk, devices

Sometimes internal harddrives are available as `/dev/sda` (with subsequent media located in `/dev/sdb` etc), and other times available as `/dev/hda`. What is the difference between the two?

Does it vary between Linux distributions, or is it based on the computer hardware, or perhaps the harddrive type?

Comment: @jasonwryan Ah, yes, that is definitely the same question, but asked in a different way. Thanks.

Comment: If by "sometimes" you mean when you run a linux kernel from 10+ years ago...

Comment: @psusi By "sometimes" I mean reading guides online that indicate `/dev/hda` should be used in a command; didn't realize the article was that old (and despite that difference, still accurate)

Answer (score 18):

Device files defined based on the controllers they are using.

1. For IDE controllers device file name is - hda, hdb, hdc..
2. For SCSI and SATA controllers device file name is - sda, sdb, sdc..

Comment: Actually, I'm in an Ubuntu 14.10 laptop right now, and my internal 2.5" IDE drive is showing up as `/dev/sda`. I can also attest to a desktop machine running the current Debian version using a 3.5" IDE-connected drive is showing up as `sda` as well.

Comment: I found that it was changed in drivers, so devices now are shown as /dev/sda. If you use old drivers, the names will be the same as I described [link](http://superuser.com/questions/75102/any-reason-why-ide-disk-hda1-shows-up-as-sda1-under-knoppix-live-cd)

Comment: Linux has treated IDE drives as scsi and hdx has been unused for a decade or so.